# How to boot from external HDD?

Tags: boot, live-usb, external-hdd, bootable, solus

The laptop I'm using has Solus installed on it, but I accidentally bricked it while trying to get the right video driver. It's a MacBook Air. I have a HDD with a partition containing a live version of the newest Solus, but the laptop isn't recognizing any external media as bootable. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Shut down your pc and restart it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>  which displays the boot selection menu.
2. Click on name of your hard disk(external), then it will boot from your external hard disk

If you are using MacOS, you can select `System Preferences` from the Apple menu, click on `Startup Disk,` select the name of your external hard drive, and click on `Restart.`

Comment: The boot menu does not display the drive. Also, MacOS does not exist on the machine anymore. It boots from its internal drive, but it has the wrong video driver installed, so the only thing it displays is a blinking cursor in the top left corner.

Comment: @DroidMonkey  your external hard drive is working or not? Check connector or something which can be responsible.

Comment: The HDD is perfectly functional. The machine will not recognize any bootable media at all.

Comment: BIOS menu is not available.

Comment: Hold on option key it will open startup manager, which allows you to open other disks.

Comment: That does nothing. I just found some different instructions for accessing the BIOS; I'll try them when I get home.

Comment: The external disk isn't showing up in this menu either.

Comment: Make sure that you have turned on boot from usb and boot priority is set to USB

Comment: Get another USB/external/disk or cable.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: if it's just your video that's hosed perhaps you can do a blind install of a ssh-server and the debug the problem over ssh.

Comment: Can you get to a different terminal console with [ctrl]-[alt]-[F3] when on the 'blinking cursor' screen?